# WCF netHttpBinding on Windows 7

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding, .net-4.5, nettcpbinding

I currently have a client/server application written in .NET 4.0 using WCF with a netTcpBinding to provide full duplex messaging between my servers and my client applications. The server is a self hosted application up on AWS EC2. The client is a Window 7 application installed on my customers PCs.

The problem I now have is that one of my new customers is insisting that my applications connects via their in house MS ISA 2004 Proxy server rather than going straight out to the Internet to connect to my servers.

Problem 1:

netTcpBinding is not Proxy aware. I have suggested that the customer installs MS Firewall Client for ISA Server to route all winsock traffic via the proxy and to simply add a new allowed protocol to the proxy server. Apparently this is not possible as the machines in the building are too locked down to install this software so this is not an option. (Hmmmmm)

Problem 2:

I had the bright idea of upgrading to .NET 4.5 and changing to netHttpBinding allowing for Duplex communications over HTTP using WebSockets so a proxy should just allow this through. My server is Windows Server 2012 so not problem. All works well on Windows 8. The problem I have is that non of my customers use Windows 8 and are unlikely to for a number of years. Currently netHttpBinding is only supported on Windows 8 and Server 2012. (Annoying!)

The question I have is does anyone know of a third party library I can use to produce a custom WCF binding in .NET 4 that will allow me to connect to a .NET 4.5 netHttpBinding or can anyone point me in the direction of any other way to overcome this proxy issue whilst retaining duplex communications?

Comment: What about tunneling software (Proxifier for instance) or VPN?

Comment: The customer IT do not want to install any third party software or have to reconfigure the network beyond the ISA server they already have. Not very helpful

Answer (score 0):

It's not accurate that .NET 4.5 is available only on Windows 8.
It is actually supported up to Vista SP2.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z6watww(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of that. The issue is not .NET 4.5 at all but netHttpBinding as it uses a different version of http.sys that is only available on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012.

Comment: I had no idea, thank you for letting me know! (Reference: http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=1210051&printmode=true). I was considering using netHttpBinding for a future project but now that option is off the radar. May I ask what solution you adopted?

Comment: I ended up using netTcpBinding still and installing the ISA Proxy Client software. Not ideal but it work. I am writing a browser version now using SignalR to work directly with the browser rather than a Windows App as a client. (http://signalr.net/)